# Check "Pointer Incompatibility" warning programmatically

Tags: objective-c, gcc

I have the following protocol and class to start with...

```
@protocol AnimalProtocol <NSObject> // this will be my global interface

@interface Animal : NSObject // and a super class
@interface Animal () <AnimalProtocol> // take note, I hid the protocol in .m file
```

Now I have an AnimalList class with the addAnimal() method...

```
@interface AnimalList : NSObject
+ (void)addAnimal:(Animal <AnimalProtocol> *)animal;
```

Now say if I subclass Animal, e.g. Reptile...

```
@interface Reptile : Animal
```

If I try to add an instance of Reptile using the addAnimal() method like so,

```
Reptile *lizard = [[Reptile alloc] init];
[AnimalList addAnimal:lizard];
```

it will generate a warning..

> "Incompatible pointer types sending "Reptile *" to parameter of type "Animal  *"

which is true since I hid the protocol on the super class Animal. In order to remove this warning I need to include the protocol declaration on my Reptile class as well OR show the AnimalProtocol on the .h of Animal class.

My question is, how do I generate a programmatic version of the GCC warning mentioned? I would like my addAnimal() method to be really strict and if Reptile class didn't include that protocol, I would like to throw an exception.

Note: I have tried

```
[[lizard class] conformsToProtocol:@protocol(AnimalProtocol)]
```

but it didn't work. It knew, that Reptile is a subclass of Animal which "invisibly" implements AnimalProtocol. But the GCC warning was able to detect it. So I would like to know how to do this programmatically.

Comment: There is not a 1:1 correspondence between what the compiler can detect and what you can check at runtime.  In general, runtime knows nothing about the "visibility" of definitions due to the way things are scoped at compile time.

Comment: What's the point of the `AnimalProtocol` protocol? And why does `Animal` conform to it in private yet you require the `addAnimal:` method to only accept `Animal` objects that also conform to `AnimalProtocol`. As you have it, `Reptile` does NOT conform to the `AnimalProtocol` protocol.

Comment: If you want to test whether Reptile supports a given function, use `respondsToSelector`.

Comment: Do you mean you want to check does the subclass of `Animal` provides its own implementation of `AnimalProtocol` (not inherited from parent)? Also, it is unlikely your Xcode still using GCC instead of Clang.

Comment: @rmaddy the purpose of the protocol is to define the required methods. The Animal class implements those methods and lays the foundation for future subclassing. Animal and AnimalProtocol will be contained inside the framework that I am creating.

Now I allow devs to create custom subclasses of Animal outside the framework, but in order for them to integrate their custom subclass to the singleton AnimalList, it must be a subclass of Animal and must implement the protocol as well - this ensures that the subclass really overridden the required methods

Comment: @BryanChen yes that's what I am hoping for. that the subclass explicitly provides its own implementation, otherwise just call [super method]. But it is important for me that the subclass must be aware that those methods exist and are needed to be overriden

Comment: @HotLicks unfortunately respondsToSelector is not dynamic. its hard to maintain overtime... especially when I refactor my protocol, then I have to add that many selector conditions as well..

Comment: Well, you're doing something very odd, and there's no "accidental" solution.  So you're going to have to compromise one way or the other.